# bootstrap-table missing sort button in column and pagelist not selectable

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

bootstrap table not showing sort icons and pagelist select option only have 1 pagesize listed even though there is pagelist.

below is the imported library:

```
<script src="PLUGINS/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="PLUGINS/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="PLUGINS/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="PLUGINS/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="PLUGINS/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="PLUGINS/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table id="userListTable"  style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="firstName">First Name</th>
            <th data-field="lastName">Last Name</th>
            <th data-field="userName">User Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userListTable').bootstrapTable({
        pagination: true,
        search: true,
        sidePagination: 'server',
        pageSize: 5,
        pageList: [5, 10, 50, 100, 200],
        showButtonIcons: true,
        url: 'test.jsp'
     });
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the bootstrap-table documentation https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#pagination. , try to set your table props via data-attributes. Check that you use compatible latest js libraries(bootstrap, etc.)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Hello, Bootstrap Table!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table data-toggle="table" data-page-size="1" data-pagination="true" data-page-list="[1,2,5]">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
          <th data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
          <th data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>$1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>$1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>$1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>$1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>$1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, turns out I missed the popper.js file which is also required. weird that google console did not post error or the bootstrap mentioned this is needed until looking at the page source (which they include some sample code without viewing the page source which include sources not related to said sample). I will mark this as answer. Thank you very much